# Get name of authenticated windows user

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-authentication

So here's what I'm attempting to do:

I want to secure a particular virtual directory on an ASP.NET application using Windows Authentication. The virtual directory only has one file, default.aspx. In the code-behind, I simply want to get the Windows username of the user who logged in but no matter what property I use, it returns the security context of the application.

I need the site itself to run under the context of the "AppContext" user for file permissions, etc. However, to determine whether the user is authorized to access the site, I need to use that user's Windows domain credentials.

```
IIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

logger.Info("Windows username: " + windowsIdentity.Name);
logger.Info("System.Environment.Username: " + System.Environment.UserName);
logger.Info("HttpContext: " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

The output is:

```
Windows username: DOMAIN\AppContext
System.Environment.Username: AppContext
HttpContext:
```

Assuming I'm logging in as myself and my Windows username is "Scott", I'd expect HttpContext to return "DOMAIN\Scott", but it returns nothing. I do get the Windows authentication dialog when attempting to access the virtual directory and I can successfully authenticate as "Scott". In the IIS7 Authentication dialog, all authentication mechanisms are turned off except for "Windows Authentication".

The strange thing is that I have another site where it's working just fine and I can't figure out what the difference is. The only difference I can see is that the working site is an actual IIS website and the one I'm currently working on is a virtual directory.

The output fom the working site is below. This is what I'm trying to replicate on the virtual directory but I must be missing something.

```
Windows username: DOMAIN\Scott
System.Environment.Username: AppContext
HttpContext: DOMAIN\Scott
```

ADDITIONAL NOTES:

- Neither site has an `<identity>` element in web.config.
- `<authentication mode="Windows" />` is set properly.
- Both the virtual directory and the site have only Windows Authentication enabled in IIS.
- The code is being executed in the `Page_Init` method.
- **The bottom line is, I simply need to let the site itself run under the security context of the "AppContext" user (which the AppPool is configured to run as) but I need to get the currently logged in user's name in the default.aspx.cs code behind.**

Comment: What's the authentication mode in your Web.config? Is it `<authentication mode="Windows" />` ?

Comment: Also make sure that Anonymous Authentication is disabled for your project (select the Web Forms project, then hit F4 to open the Properties panel) and that Windows Authentication is enabled. These are both project properties.

Comment: Updated the question to include the fact that '<authentication mode="Windows"' is set properly. Also, I don't want to disable Anonymous authentication for the entire project, it's just one virtual directory underneath the project.

Comment: when are you calling it?

Comment: Daniel, in the notes portion at the bottom of my question, it mentions I'm calling it in Page_Init

Answer (score 0):

Check your authorization settings.

If the resource is accessible by anonymous user - and no resource earlier in the request chain of the browser triggered an authentication - IIS will not authenticate the user.

So, you must have Windows authentication, and deny anonymous access, to see a user name in HttpContext.

Comment: Oddly enough, when I add <authorization><deny users="?"/></authorization> to the web.config inside the virtual directory, it never lets me log in. It just infinitely re-displays the Windows authentication dialog. Might have something to do with it...

Comment: Yeah. Not authorized - you remove anonymous but give noone right to log in ;) Endless loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Web.config inside folder and set `<authentication mode="Windows"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it in System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: That comes back as a NULL value as well.

Comment: So in that case you should really double check that Windows Authentication is the only one enabled.  If I recall correctly the server will try Anonymous, Basic, Forms, and Windows in order so if one of the others are enabled first then it will pick that to authenticate the user. To confirm this you can disable the auto authenticate feature in IE.  Instructions here: http://bit.ly/1pkeKIo Make sure you are getting prompted to log in.